# Weird results with openmp reduction

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

In have this class:

```
template <typename C, typename R, typename D>
class myClass{
    public:
    R Query(const C &query);
    ...
    private:
    struct Compare{
        D val;
        size_t index;
    };
    #pragma omp declare reduction(minimum : Compare : omp_out = omp_in.val < omp_out.val ? omp_in : omp_out)
    std::vector<C> values;
    ...
}


template <typename C, typename R, typename D>
R Cache<C,R,D>::Query(const C &query){
    Compare min;
    R result;
    if(!values.empty()){
            #pragma omp parallel for reduction(minimum:min)
            for(size_t i=1; i<values.size(); i++){
                D d = distance->compute(query, values[i]);
                std::cout<<" distance("<<query<<" "<<values[i].code<<")= "<<d;
                if(d < min.val){
                    std::cout<<" NEW MIN!";
                    min.val = d;
                    min.index = i;
                }
                std::cout<<std::endl;
            }
        std::cout<<"min.val="<<min.val<<std::endl;
   }
...
```

`D d = distance->compute(query, values[i]);` value is correct (and the following print too).

However, for some weird reason, everytime that the `parallel for` is computed, `min.val` is `0` (in few words the last `cout` prints always `min.val=0`).

Obviously this is not the whole code and I made it as simple as possible.

Comment: It's spelled reduction(min:  min.val) and you would need at least lastprivate(min.index) and some initialization of min.val.  others here have insisted on the user defined reduction. Wasn't there a compiler warning?

Comment: Please learn how to make a proper [mcve]. This would drastically improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the initalizer for user declared reduction:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(minimum : Compare : omp_out = omp_in.val < omp_out.val ? omp_in : omp_out) \
                initializer (omp_priv=Compare{std::numeric_limits<D>::max(), -1})
```

Alternatively, you can add a member initialization:

```
template <typename D>
class Foo {
struct Compare{
    D val {std::numeric_limits<D>::max()};
    int index {-1};
};
```

This is more general and will make sure the program works correctly even without `-fopenmp`.

Comment: He also needs to assign `min=Compare{value,index}`. In his for loop he changes the member variables and the reduction is declared on the struct.

Comment: @Kochoba The original loop body is correct. No need to create/assign a new struct. Modifying the members is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The initializer is not needed at all If you initialize the struct inside the parallel block

```
 #pragma omp declare reduction( \
    minimum : Compare : omp_out = omp_in.val < omp_out.val ? omp_in : omp_out\
    ) 

#pragma omp parallel reduction(minimum:min)
{
    D d = distance->compute(query, values[0]);
    min = Compare{d,0}
    #pragma omp for
    for(size_t i=1; i<values.size(); i++){
        d = distance->compute(query, values[i]);
        if(d < min.val)
            min = Compare{d,i};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, ` error: expected end of line before ‘[’ token` , why?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If your compiler does not support the initializer you can try the second solution without the initializer in the reduction declaration

Comment: 1) The comparison on the parallel section is absolutely needed, 2) the `[]` in the standard are merely a syntrax hint in the standard indicating that the *initializer-clause* is optional. 3) `RAND_MAX` is a terrible choice.

Comment: @Zulan Tha question was why the initial code was producing weird results. 1) Yes, the comparison is needed without it the code becomes sequential, not relevant though with the question. 2) Yes, the initializer is optional and does not answer the question why his compiler raises an error. 3) This is an example code. You can initialize to whatever fits your needs. Again all these comments are not relevant to the question

Comment: I am pointing out the aspects of your answer that are wrong. If you don't believe me, just try it.

Comment: @Zulan I have tried my answer and it works. I don't really see what wrongs you pointed out. What I see is that you marked my answer as not useful and re-posted the same answer with different initialization. So if you don't believe me just try it. Anyways I was just trying to help a guy you obviously trying to raise your reputation. Even if the initialization was an issue for you, you could point that out with a nice constructive comment.

Comment: The suggested loop code is incorrect because it overwrites `min` regardless whether `d` is minimal or not. You **must** do that check inside the loop like in original question (or your updated version). Contrary to what you write the reduction **does not** do any comparison within one thread. It only does so for combining the thread-local minima. Your initializer is syntactically wrong, there are not supposed to be any literal `[]` there.

Comment: @Zulan Thank you for your comment I updated my answer with your suggestions.